# iOS 5: Some references not being retained

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm seeing some interesting behavior now that I'm using iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2.  I have an singleton class that contains a UIImage variable and an NSString variable, but for some reason the UIImage variable is never retained even though I'm using properties.  I've used this same code for singletons in other projects and it's always worked fine but it seems broken in iOS 5.  And, by the way, I am NOT using ARC.

Here is an example of what the header file looks like:

```
@interface MYSingleton : NSObject {

    NSString *aString;
    UIImage *anImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *anImage;

+ (MYSingleton *) instance;

@end
```

And here is the corresponding implementation file:

```
@implementation MYSingleton

static MYSingleton *instance = nil;

@synthesize aString, anImage;

- (void) dealloc {
    [aString release];
    [anImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (MYSingleton *) instance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            [[MYSingleton alloc] init]; // assignment not done here
        }
    }

    return instance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return instance; 
        }
    }

    return nil; 
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;    
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;  
}

- (void)release {
    // do nothing    
}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

@end
```

By popular demand, here is how I assign a value to the UIImage variable:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController  *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    id image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    MYSingleton *m = [MYSingleton instance];
    m.anImage = image
}
```

I also noticed a perhaps related difference in iOS 5 but with a category I created.  This category was for UIDevice.  I added a method that returned the platform as a string.  I cach the string in a static variable I declared at the top of the category's implementation file.  The first time the method was called the static variable is nil so the value is calculated and stored in the static variable.  On subsequent calls to the method the cached variable is returned.  This worked fine in iOS 4 but in 5 when ever this method is called more than once an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error is thrown (except when I'm stepping through the code).

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't show where you are creating "anImage" or how it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

First, that singleton is a bunch of nonsense (Yes, I know it is from the docs -- still a bunch of nonsense).  If you want to implement a singleton, just do:

```
@implementation MYSingleton
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
     static MYSingleton *instance = nil;
     static dispatch_once_t once;
     dispatch_once(&once, ^{
          instance = [[self alloc] init]; 
     });
     return instance;
}
... etc ...
@end
```

All the rest of that is a waste of typing.

Secondly, you don't show the code related to the thing that is crashing.  Best guess, though, is that you have code that is doing:

```
anImage = [... some random method that returns an image....];
```

When you really meant:

```
self.anImage = [ ... ];
```

That is, you aren't using the setter and the image isn't retained.   Maybe this was a change you introduced recently.  Maybe the image was a singleton in prior releases due to caching.

Hard to say without seeing more code.

Comment: +1 on self.anImage likely being it.  Haven't seen dispatch_once singleton - interesting.  The doc'd singleton isn't necessarily incorrect, just likely overly defensive.  A waste of buffer when pasting ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wish I had a dime for all the different ways I've seen the singleton pattern implemented.  This is a new one so thanks.  As for how I do the assignment, please see my edit.  As I said this worked in iOS 4 but not in 5.

Comment: That is a GCD-ized version of what I've used for 22 years (on many teams).  The reality of the "recommended" pattern is that it just hides bugs and makes it more difficult to refactor into a non-singleton later.